# Could not find actionbarsherlock.apk in Navigation Drawer Page Sliding Tab Strip

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have download all 3 files related to **Navigation Drawer Page Sliding Tab Strip**. and now, 
It is showing error :

```
actionbarsherlock] Could not find actionbarsherlock.apk!
PagerSlidingTab] Could not find PagerSlidingTab.apk!
```

I have followed steps as per this link : [Managing Projects from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

But after that I am getting error : `Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;`

By some Tutorials, I have solved this issue but now I am getting error : `ClassNotFound Exception` even though it is there in `AndroidManiFest`.
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you explain step-by-step what you have done? If you want to use those as the library, that's not the correct way. Please follow [Android Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

Comment: There are some questions related to "Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex" on here, but it seems that there is no definite solution. Example are [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687773/android-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-null), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087341/multiple-dex-files-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397385/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-java-nio-bufferoverfl).

Comment: @AndrewT., I have solved that error. But now, new error : ClassNot Found even though it is there in AndroidManiFest.